# Why insert into select field1, field2 ... from table doesn't work with decimals?

Tags: sql-server, math, insert, overflow

When I try this on SQL Server 2014:

```
INSERT INTO B_G049
    SELECT B049_Z001, B049_Z002, ObjectId1, ObjectId7, 43099 AS value
    FROM B_G049
    WHERE value = 42734;
```

with decimals columns, I get an error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 56
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

I have never noticed such problem with copy rows between the same structure tables (in this case same table is input and output) using

```
INSERT INTO table1 
    SELECT (list of columns)
    FROM table1  
    WHERE (condition)
```

Comment: show your table structure .. most probably you are trying to insert in wrong column

Comment: define your column names on insert to verify you are inserting the right values into the right columns `insert into B_G049 ( col1name, col2name, col3name...) values select ...`

Comment: Define your columns in your insert statement and re-run your query. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: You have one integer which is too big for its destination column. So this heavily depends on the actual data in your table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The reason was other order of fields. INSERT INTO table1 (list of columns)
    SELECT (same list of columns)
    FROM table1  
    WHERE (condition)